# Getting Magento Version Using SOAP API V2 and C#

Tags: c#, magento, soap

**Background**: I have built a tool that imports sales orders from Magento to a custom application.  The function `salesOrderList()` worked fine on a customer's Magento Go store.  Then it failed on another customer's store.  The reason was the former store was version 1.6.x and the latter was 1.5.x. The function call returned two different data structures on the two versions (despite being the same API version, namely SOAP API V2), causing the problem.  So I customized the tool to expect the 1.6.x data structure first and then fall back to 1.5.x if the former failed.  Now, we have a new customer who seems to have Magento version 1.7.  The data structure seems to have changed again in 1.7 for the same function (`salesOrderList()`).

**Programmed Using**: .NET (C#); Magento SOAP API V2

**Question**: Is there a function call to determine the Magento (1.5, 1.6, etc.) version of the store we are connecting to?  I understand from another post that there is a MAGE::getVersion() call that they use in PHP, directly on the store (without SOAP API).  Is there a .NET equivalent for this when using the SOAP API?

**PS**: I had posted the same question (a little less wordy though) as *user1236916* because I had temporarily lost the login information for this account.  My apologies for the repetition.

Thanks!

Comment: by "store version", do you mean Magento version (ie: 1.4.0.0, 1.6.2.0, etc...)? Magento edition (ie: community, enterprise, go)? something else?

Comment: Create your own API and implement simple function to get magento version via `Mage::getVersion()` static function.

Comment: @OSDave, yes, I do mean Magento version numbers like 1.4.0.0, 1.6.2.0, etc.

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir, thanks for the input.  But I need the .NET equivalent of it for use from C#.  I couldn't find it defined in `Reference.cs` nor in the WSDL.

Comment: Try this method `catalog_category/currentStore` in your SOAP call.

Comment: I can give you a few sample links at the moment. Specifically check `EZ Newsletter Magento API` (http://www.molotovbliss.com/net-c-api-to-magento-via-xml-rpc) [C# Lib API](http://code.google.com/p/csharlibformagexmlrpcapi/) [Using Magento API with WCF](http://cgeers.com/2010/02/11/using-the-magento-core-api-with-wcf/)

Comment: The Magento version isn't available through the API. That said, I believe the WS-I compliance mode setting under *System > Configuration > Services > Magento Core API > WSI compliance* might be responsible for the difference in the returned data structure (for the 1.6 and 1.7 instances).

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir, thanks again but we use SOAP and not XML RPC.  I guess I shall just have to settle for user-input of the store version for now.

Comment: @Lrrr, it only returns the store view and not the store version.  But I did learn a bit from this comment and hence I've upvoted it.  Thank you.

Comment: @Vinai, this should be useful, thanks!  Wish I could upvote it twice.  I shall definitely have one of our customers try it.  Do you know how we can set this in Magento Go?  The _System > Configuration_ link does not have a _Services_ option in Magento Go.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: I'm sorry, I never set up a Go store, I don't know if that feature is available there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Magento core API is known to be very limited in the calls it provides by default. There is no call that returns the Magento version out of the box.

More infomation on the Magento core API can be found on the [official Magento site](http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/magento_core_api).

That being said the Magento API is designed to be extended and to do so is not overly difficult. You will need to create a Magento module that extends one of the core API resources (you will need to do this in PHP and have access to the Magento installation itself).

See [this post](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-api-v2/) for more information on how to extend the V2 Magento API.

In your extended API class simple create a function like so:

```
public function getVersion()
{
    // static method to return the Magento version within the app
    return Mage::getVersion();
}
```

Comment: as the stores belong to third parties who use our integration tool, the option of gaining access to the Magento installation is not there.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Though it will not be practical in my case to gain access to the Magento installation of customers, I have marked this respone as the answer because it clearly summarizes the facts surrounding the general issue (of getting version from Magento) and can hence serve as a good reference to other developers on this matter.